# How to call a parent variable in a nested function

Tags: python, function, scope, nested, python-nonlocal

I've written a denoising function with [`cv2`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/) and [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), to be applied on both my training and test image data.

The functions (at current) are as follows:

```
def denoise_single_image(img_path):
    nonlocal data
    img = cv2.imread(f'../data/jpeg/{data}/{img_path}')
    dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img, 10,10,7,21)
    cv2.imwrite(f'../processed_data/jpeg/{data}/{img_path}', dst)
    print(f'{img_path} denoised.')
 
def denoise(data):
    img_list = os.listdir(f'../data/jpeg/{data}')
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        tqdm.tqdm(executor.map(denoise_single_image, img_list))
```

`data` is to be either `train` or `test`, as necessary; `img_list` is a list of all image names in that directory.

I need to create the `denoise_single_image()` function before `denoise()`, otherwise `denoise()` won't recognize it; but I need to define `data` before I create `denoise_single_image()`. This seems to be a catch-22, unless I can figure out how to tell `denoise_single_image()` to refer to a variable that exists one level up.

`nonlocal` doesn't work because it assumes that `data` has already been defined in this environment. Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Any reason why data can't be globally scoped? you do not seem to need to modify it anywhere, so it's not a bad use case.

Comment: @m.oulmakki I've tried both `global` and `nonlocal`. While it runs (technically) with `global`, it doesn't seem to acknowledge the existence of anything. Adding `print(data)` after `global data` didn't return anything.

Comment: You do not need to define `denoise_signal_image` before defining `denoise`, only before *calling* `denoise`. Further, `nonlocal` applies to *lexical* scopes, not the scope in which `denoise_single_image` might be called. The parameter `data` is *not* the `nonlocal` variable `data` that `denoise_single_image` refers to.

Comment: You have two choices: make `data` global so that `denoise` can set its value before calling `denoise_single_image`, or make `data` an argument to `denoise_single_image` and use something like `lambda x: denose_single_image("train", x)` as the first argument to `map`.

Comment: @chepner I would think this would work, but `tqdm.tqdm(executor.map(lambda x: denoise_single_image(data, x), img_list))` seems to stall the function. I see nothing in the output directory after a few minutes, and I don't get any `{img_path} denoised` responses, even after defining `denoise_single_image(data, img_path)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the iterable in `executor.map` to be a tuple of arguments, which can then split in your other function.

```
executor.map(denoise_single_image, ((img_path, data) for img_path in img_list))

def denoise_single_image(inputs):
    img_path, data = inputs
    # etc
```

But in your case I would just modify the individual image paths like so

```
executor.map(denoise_single_image, (f'jpeg/{data}/{img_path}' for img_path in img_list))

def denoise_single_image(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(f'../data/{img_path}')
    dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img, 10,10,7,21)
    cv2.imwrite(f'../processed_data/{img_path}', dst)
    print(f'{img_path.split('/')[-1]} denoised.')
```